# Comparison on Ciphertext with Helib

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Is it possible to do a greater than homomorphic comparison in the form ($c_1 < c_2$) on two ciphertexts using [Helib](https://github.com/shaih/HElib/)?

The equal comparison ($c_1 == c_2$) can be done in modulus 2 by adding both ciphertexts. Does it give any multiplication and/or addition combination to obtain the greater than comparison ( $<$) on binary numbers?

Comment: can  (c1==c2) be done in higher modulo? Sorry I am new in this

Comment: i think, it cannot be done in higher modulus, because the property of OR-Circuit can be better exploited in Helib with binary numbers

Comment: If you want to compute the homomorphic comparison between positive integers, please check out this paper, http://www.acad.ro/sectii2002/proceedings/doc2015-3s/08-Togan.pdf, that implements the comparison operators over HElib.

Answer (score 3):

On the paper [Low Depth Circuits for Efficient Homomorphic Sorting](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/274.pdf#5) (page 5), the authors present circuits to homomorphically evaluate comparisons.

Their "Less Than Circuit" compares $\ell$-bit integers in the following way:

They define a bit level "less than": $f(x, y) = y \cdot (x + 1) \mod 2$  (where $x$ and $y$ are encryptions of bits).

They define a bit level "equal to":  $g(x, y) = y + x + 1 \mod 2$.

Then, the less than circuit for two encrypted $\ell$-bit integers is

$$C_{LT}(X, Y) =  \sum_{k=1}^{\ell} (f(X_k, Y_k) \cdot \prod_{k<t<\ell}g(X_t, Y_t))  \mod 2$$

where $X = (X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_\ell)$ is a vector of ciphertexts in which each $X_k$ is the encryption of the $k$-th bit of the first plaintext (and the same for $Y$ regarding the second plaintext).

Since the only thing it requires is the ability to encrypt bit a bit and to homomorphically operate $\mod 2$, it seems you can evaluate this circuit using Helib.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

The idea sounds good, but i get different outputs depending on the binary numbers chosen. For example: ct1 = Encrypt(1001); ct2 = Encrypt(1000); // the reulst is 0001 ct1 = Encrypt(1010); ct2 = Encrypt(0111) // the result is 1000 Should i care about something else?

Comment: But how can you get $1000$? The result should be either $0$ or $1$, since all the operations are done $\mod 2$.

Comment: you are right, all operations are done in $mod 2$, that is why the numbers to encrypt only contain $0$ or $1$. In Helib, each number of $1001$ is treated as it is alone($1$-bit) during the operations, so adding $1001$ and $1000$ return $0001$. The problem is, your idea is c orrect if we habe $1$-bit number, but not for $4$-bit number or more. The algorithm proposed in the paper above cannot be performed with Helib. Helib cannot compute multiple multiplications with one ciphertext in a loop.

Comment: @leproPapi what about if you encode your integer 1001 by yourself into 4 different plaintexts and then encrypt instead of put them inside of 4 slots of the same plaintext?

Comment: And even if you put them inside the slots of a single plaintext, I think you can multiple them by using the automorphism to rotate the bits...

Comment: @victor the goal is to compare which of the both $1001$ and $1000$ is greater. So you still need to know which of the most significant bits is greater if you split the numbers. The important issue is to know which of the $1$-bit plaintexts encrypted are the most signifcant bits.